# Getting a complete copy of a branch from github

Tags: github, branch

The repository I'm using has a branch called `next`.  When I cloned the repository initially, it set up my default branch as `master`.  I've switched my default branch to `next` online, and I've checked out the `next` branch (using `-t` and `-b` options) on my local clone.  Typing `git branch` shows I have two branches checked out (`master` and `next`), and `next` is the active branch.

All fine and dandy, but there are files which exist in branch that do not exist in `master`.  I had assumed that when I fetched upstream and checked out the new branch, that the missing files would appear in my local repo...  However, they do not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

If you don't have any local changes (which would get clobbered).